# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MCA'

Tags: python

I want to do correspondence analysis for the categorical features in my dataset but get this error.

```
import mca
mca_counts = mca.MCA(test.drop('ID', axis=1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    mca_counts = mca.MCA(test.drop('ID', axis=1))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MCA'
```

Comment: Are you shadowing it? Do you have `mca.py` somewhere in your package or in the directory you run your shell from?

Comment: I have mca.py in the directory I run the shell from. mca.mca seems to work but I get this error: TypeError: Could not operate 0 with block values unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the latest version of the library in PyPI is 1.0, where the class is called [`mca.mca`](https://github.com/esafak/mca/blob/1.0/src/mca.py#L16). It was renamed to [`mca.MCA`](https://github.com/esafak/mca/blob/v1.0.1/src/mca.py#L39) only in 1.0.1, but that version for some reason has never made it to PyPI. Consider either using `mca.mca`, or reinstalling it from git, or finding something less abandoned.

Comment: Thanks...mca.mca seems to work but I get this error when I use it  TypeError: Could not operate 0 with block values unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I get the error message `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`